# Faster solution to puzzle: fill table with results of multiplication signs

Tags: logic, problem-solving, puzzle

Fill + or - in the blank squares below so that:

- for each row, the sign in the rightmost (gray) column is the result of the multiplication of the signs in the row
- for each column, the sign in the bottom (gray) row is the result of the multiplication of the signs in the column

The rule is the same for multiplication, i.e., (-)(+)(-) results in (+)

[image]

The problem asks **how many distinct solutions** are possible to fill the whole grid.

I know that the answer is **4**, but is there a faster solution than trying out all combinations?

Comment: Picking a sign in certain squares will determine signs in other squares. Show that there are two squares whose signs determine all the rest.

Comment: Extending the comment of @Blue, one approach is to select the bottom row, left cell and middle cell.  You would then have to show that for each of the four possible choices: [1] Every other cell is completely determined and [2] The result is a satisfactory solution.

Comment: My thinking (which is only one way to do it) is $-$ requires an odd number of $-$s and $+$ an even.  The middle row, $_ + _ = +$ requires and even number or $-$ so either no $-$x (all $+$x) or $2 -$s (all $-$s).  The first column ($+__ = -$) requires an odd number of $-$ so exactly $1-$ (and the other must be $+$) and if the middle row has both $+$ or both  $-$ will determine which one is which.   The second column determines the remainder are one $+$ and one $-$ and two choices of which.  That gives us so far two choices of two or four choices.  The final two squares will be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the problem to a set of linear constraints on a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ (the [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of size $2$ where addition is XOR and multiplication is AND). The $+$ signs map to $0$s, the $-$ signs map to $1$s. You have $7$ unknowns and $6$ linear constraints, and you want to find the dimension of the solution space. With

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
0&a_1&a_2&\bf1\\\hline
a_3&0&a_4&\bf0\\\hline
a_5&a_6&a_7&\bf0\\\hline
\bf1&\bf1&\bf1\\\hline
\end{array}

your constraints are

$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&1
}
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_5\\a_6}=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\1\\1\\1}\;.
$$

You need to find the rank of the $6\times7$ matrix of constraints.
I don’t know how to get Wolfram|Alpha to work over $\mathbb F_2$, but [here](https://matrixer.davidaugustat.com/?field=2&exp=rowreduce(%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%3B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%3B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%3B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%3B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%3B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D))’s a calculation of the reduced row echelon form using an online matrix tool that works over finite fields. The result is

$$
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
}\;,
$$

so as expected the rank is $5$, leaving a $2$-dimensional solution space with $2^2=4$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My thinking (which is only one way to do it) is to note: A $-$ result requires an odd number of $-$s and an $+$ result an even number of $-$s.

The middle row, (Blank, +, Blank yields +) requires an even number of $-$s.  So either no $-$x  or $2 -$s (all $-$s). In either cases both cells must be either both $-$ or both $+$.  That is our first choice:

So we start with:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
+&&&\bf-\\\hline
\color{blue}A&+&\color{blue}A&\bf+\\\hline
&&&\bf+\\\hline
\bf-&\bf-&\bf-\\\hline
\end{array}$

Now that leads directly to the  The first column (+, A, Blank yields -) requires an odd number of $-$s.  So exactly $1-$ and $2+$s.  That means whatever $\color{blue}A$ is the third square must be the opposite.

So...

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
+&&&\bf-\\\hline
\color{blue}A&+&\color{blue}A&\bf+\\\hline
\color{blue}{-A}&&&\bf+\\\hline
\bf-&\bf-&\bf-\\\hline
\end{array}$

The second column, (Blank, +, Blank yields -) requires an odd number of $-$s, and that can be either of the missing squares and the other missing square must be the opposite.  Which one is our second choice.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
+&\color{red}{B}&&\bf-\\\hline
\color{blue}A&+&\color{blue}A&\bf+\\\hline
\color{blue}{-A}&\color{red}{-B}&&\bf+\\\hline
\bf-&\bf-&\bf-\\\hline
\end{array}$

The top row has two of three cells filled so third cell is determined entirely by our second choice:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
+&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{-B}&\bf-\\\hline
\color{blue}A&+&\color{blue}A&\bf+\\\hline
\color{blue}{-A}&\color{red}{-B}&&\bf+\\\hline
\bf-&\bf-&\bf-\\\hline
\end{array}$

For the final cell, I use a slightly different logic.  A $+$ can only result by multiplying two of the same together (either $+\cdot + = +$ or $-\cdot - = +$) and a $-$ can only result from multplying two opposites together (either $-\cdot + = -$ or $+\cdot - = -$).  So if we look at the third row we must have the last cell being the same as $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}$.

But if we look at the third column we must have the last cell being the opposite of $\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A}$

so:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
+&\color{red}{B}&\color{red}{-B}&\bf-\\\hline
\color{blue}A&+&\color{blue}A&\bf+\\\hline
\color{blue}{-A}&\color{red}{-B}&{\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}\text{by row}}\over{-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})\text{by column}}&\bf+\\\hline
\bf-&\bf-&\bf-\\\hline
\end{array}$

Okay... we have some options depending on how often $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}=-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$.

If $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}$ always equals $-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$ then all choices are valid. And as we have two choices for $\color{blue}A$ and two choices for $\color{red}B$ for a total of $4$ solutions.

Or if $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}$ never equals $-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$ we have a contradiction, and we have $0$ solutions.

Of if $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}$ sometimes equals $-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$ depending on the options of $\color{blue}A$ or $\color{red}B$ we may have $1$ or $2$ solutions depending on the number of possible solutions to $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}=-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$.

As $\color{blue}{-A}\cdot\color{red}{-B}$ always equals $-(\color{red}{-B}\cdot \color{blue}{A})$ we have four solutions.